# C# Job Scheduler

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I want to implement a scheduler in my Project. My aim is to implement an ETL process.
That means at each end of the day i want to read today data from my database then create an XML file and upload it to some remote system.
    For the implementation i completed all the process except scheduling.

If anyone know please help me the following things.

1. Add a new class for handling scheduling
2. How to use a timer in c# to create a scheduler(how to add and use)
3. How to invoke that timer at a specified time 11.45 PM(23.45)

Pls provider some sample code

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Ususally questions that are too broad or simply ask for source code are not very good questions. Luckily there is [advice on how to improve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the built in data export functionality in your DBMS? I'm sure all DBMS' have this sort of thing built in through jobs.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at `Quartz.net` - http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: +1. That is a complex theme, and Quartz.Net is about the only available  library.

Answer (score 1):

I tried something simple job scheduling in console applications.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Quartz;
    using Quartz.Impl;
    using Quartz.Job;
    using System.Windows;
    namespace WindowsTrainingTasks
    {
        public partial class Schedulerexample : Window
        {
            public Schedulerexample()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                IScheduler quartzScheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler();
                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<HelloJob>()
                   .WithIdentity("HelloJob", "group1")
                   .Build();
                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("DAMMetadataSyncTrigger")
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
                .RepeatForever())
                .Build();
                quartzScheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
                quartzScheduler.Start();
            }
        }
        public class HelloJob : IJob
        {
            public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Xenovex Technologies", "Xenovex5");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you want to run it on a daily basis and because you have not argued that the program needs to run all the time (e.g. for communicating with the application via a WCF service), I would advise you to let your application be started from the windows scheduler.